# Variation in the context of symmetries

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, symmetry, perturbation-theory

I’m rephrasing a suggestion as a question because there was an aspect to it where I wanted to know more as well.

I have studied both general relativity and particle physics, though in both cases my experience with theory ended around the time of my general exam in graduate school (because I switched fields, did data analysis, got sick, ended with a masters, various…)

I did a project based on finding an interaction cross section assuming certain symmetries many years ago. I don’t remember exactly what I did, but I think I enforced those symmetries prior to perturbing the first order Feynman integral.

But I am now looking at the Einstein-Hilbert action and see that if the spacetime background is Schwarszchild, then R=0, and the action is zero. Obviously the equations of motion still exist.

What’s the difference here? Why can the relevant relationships between the form factors be derived (if I recall) in particle physics but not in this instance of general relativity, using symmetry constrained variations?

In the E-H action, obviously the geodesic equation can be derived and the Schwarzschild equations of motions computed, but it seems to be necessary to keep R symbolic until the geodesic equation, at which point the Christofel symbols can be evaluated.

Why the difference? Or is my 15 year old memory or past work on the summer particle physics project likely just wrong?